# How do I submit a react-native android app to the playstore?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I can't find this in any of the facebook documentation. Has anyone submitted an android app they built with react native yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/marty-wang/5a71e9d0a6a2c6d6263c) gist which outlines the process of creating a release APK file (credit to the author, marty-wang).

Once you have the release  package, you should be able to upload the APK manually through the play store.

**Edit 2016-06-01:**

The most up to date way to handle RN builds for Android and iOS would be using Fastlane - the tooling abstracts building and uploading to both the Play store, as well as to the iOS App store/Testflight. Also allows for generation of screenshots and managing store metadata in your code base. [Danial Banck has a great write up of how to do this](https://dbanck.svbtle.com/deploying-a-react-native-app-with-fastlane) that I personally have used myself and can highly recommend.